# Executar função PHP com onclick()

Tags: php, javascript, funções, onclick

Olá, tenho uma função que deveria ser executada somente ao clicar no botão filtrar, mas a página já abre com a pesquisa, com a função executada. O onclick já está no botão de filtro.

Aqui está a função:

```
function LoadFiltro(buscanova){

    var nr_cliente              = $('select[name=nr_cliente]').val();
    var nr_gc1                  = $('select[name=nr_gc1]').val();
    var nr_status               = $('select[name=nr_status]').val();
    var nr_empresa              = $("select[name='nr_empresa']").val();
    var nr_potencial_fechamento = $("select[name='nr_potencial_fechamento']").val();
    var dt_previsao_fechamento1 = $("input[name='dt_fechamento_ini']").val();
    var dt_previsao_fechamento2 = $("input[name='dt_fechamento_fim']").val();

   $.post('../App_Cad/ControlPreVendas.php', 
        {action: 'load', 
        type: 'filtro_controle', 
        nr_cliente: nr_cliente, 
        nr_gc1: nr_gc1, 
        nr_status: nr_status, 
        nr_empresa: nr_empresa, 
        nr_potencial_fechamento: nr_potencial_fechamento,
        dt_previsao_fechamento1: dt_previsao_fechamento1, 
        dt_previsao_fechamento2: dt_previsao_fechamento2,
        buscanova: buscanova},
            function(data){
                $('#resp_filtro').html(data);
            }
   );
```

E aqui o botão:

`<input type="button" value="Filtrar" class="botao" onClick="LoadFiltro(true);"/>`

Estou abrindo o body assim:

`<body onLoad="LoadFiltro(false);">`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver e obter o resultado que eu queria.

O que foi feito para dar certo foi: Retirei o atributo onLoad="LoadFiltro(false); do body e deu certo.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Felipe!

Talvez eu não seja a pessoa mais recomendada para responder sua pergunta, mas creio que seja impossível fazer javascript executar função em php diretamente... espero que alguém consiga dizer se estou errado ou certo. 
Tente passar uma variável como submit/post para a mesma pagina.

Exemplo:

index.php

```
<?
$execute = $_POST["execute"];

function teste() {
  ...
}

if (!empty($execute)) {
  teste();
}

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
  <input hidden type="text" name="execute" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Testar">
</form>

?>
```